# can i install and use, visual studio 2008 and visual studio 2010 on the same windows xp/vista

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, windows-vista

can i install and use, visual studio 2008 and visual studio 2010 on the same windows xp/vista

- have visual studio 2008 installed and working
- wnat to install visual studio 2010 and use with 2008,
- some solutions on 08 and some on 10..

any problems possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can! 
Can't add anything else, honestly! :)

Well, I personally have 2005, 2008 and 2010 installed on the same workstation, for various needs and projects. Works without any problem!

Answer (score 1):

No problems at all running both Visual Studio 2008 and 2010 side-by-side. My development box is currently set up this way.

Solutions will automatically open in the version of Visual Studio that they were created in. You can manually choose to open them in a newer version, but you will need to update them. A wizard will automatically appear that guides you through the process.

Opening a solution saved with a *newer* version of VS in an older version is not a supported scenario.
But there is a workaround: simply open the `*.sln` file in a text editor (like Notepad) and decrement the version number by 1. You'll have to do the same thing for each of the project files.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with converting a Visual Studio 2008 project to 2010, which made the program could not compile at all with every measure i took.. then I installed Visual Studio 2008 again and it turns out they can be installed in the same computer and work, but you need to open visual basic 2008 manually if you want to develop a project there..

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have any problems unless you try to develop for Windows Phone 7, which you can't currently, and may never be able to, do in Windows XP.